# How long can I travel for with 30k?

Tags: usa, europe, money, accommodation, brazil

I am a Brazilian Jiu-jitsu lover. I have travelled to a couple of places in Europe to train this year during my holidays from work and have really enjoyed the experience.

Anyway, I would like to travel (Brazil, U.S and Europe) to train at various schools on an extended break.

I have around 30,000 Euros saved up. How long realistically could I do this for with this budget?

Most academies charge in the region of 80 us dollars per month to train unlimited classes. Some more, some less.

*I want to live as cheaply as possible.

Comment: This is far too broad and the answer is going to depend very much on the lifestyle you want to live while you're travelling, so any good answer will be very specific to you and of little use to anyone else. If you stay in 5* hotels, eat in the best restaurants and fly first class, you could easily blow 30k in a month. If you live in hostels, cook for yourself and hitchhike, it could last for years.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have added a footnote to help

Comment: OK but that doesn't help with the general problem that your question is just too broad. Europe is a big place and prices vary dramatically. The US is a completely different big place and prices vary dramatically. Brazil is yet a third different big place and I bet prices vary there, too. You're going to have to look at some options and cost them up yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It's really hard to answer your question, not to say impossible.
In Europe, for example, there are huge differences in life cost between countries, and even between regions within a country.

The academy will be a minor cost compared to housing, food and travel expenses. 
In general you have to consider:

- How long you will be in each country (living longer might bring costs down since you might rent an apartment or share)
- How much you want to travel around
- Probably most important. It depends on your life style.
  You might be well sharing a room with others your you might want a private suite in an expensive hotel. You might cook at home or you go out for dinner every day.

These are all aspects you need to consider.

Having said this, have a look at the average wage per european country. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_countries_by_average_wage

As a thumb rule, a local habitant should be able to live in each country with the average salary. The fact that you don't have local knowledge and you are travelling will make your general costs higher though.

Comment: Average salary won't necessarily be enough: short term accommodation is much more expensive than long-term rental.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I totally agree. Maybe I didn't explain properly, but I meant that a local habitant should be able to live with that. This is only a reference value. His costs will be higher. But again, he might bring those down if stays longer in a place.